# pymongo MongoDB - using variables in update statement

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert (using update) address field "1.2.3.4" in below document using variable. I want it too look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550ebacab9d30b5b2d998751"), "address" : "google.com",  "1.2.3.4" : true  }
```

But instead I'm getting this one below, why ?

```
> var target = true;
> var field = "1.2.3.4";
> 
> var obj = {};
> obj[field] = target;
true
> db.repvpn.update( { "address": "google.com" },{ $set: obj } );
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.repvpn.find({"address": "google.com"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550ebacab9d30b5b2d998751"), "address" : "google.com",  "1" : { "2" : { "3" : { "4" : true } } } }
```

in my pymongo I just have below with the same result (ip = "google.com")

```
source = '1.2.3.4'
self.repvpn.update({"address": ip}, {"$set": {source: 1}})
```

Comment: [#Restrictions-on-Field-Names](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

Comment: Oh I think it's because field name can't include '.' I will convert addresses to hex in order to use as names